# How to find sales in last 30 days, last 30 to 60 days given a transaction data?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a transaction data frame as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({"id":[139,139,139,432,474,164],
              "order_date":["2022-01-01","2022-02-01","2022-02-04","2022-02-03","2022-02- 28","2022-01-24"],
                "product_id":["A","B","B","E","A","D"],
                "sales($)":[10,20,30,20,10,20]})
```

Given a `date_slicer_list=[30,60]`, I want to slice the data as shown below from the `max(order_date).`
I'm looking for a function which takes date_slicer_list as an argument so that I can give another list if I want more slices of data.

```
pd.DataFrame({"customer_id":[139,432,474,164],
              "last_30days_sales":[50,20,10,0],
              "last_30_to_60_days_sales":[10,0,0,10]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `cut` and `unstack`:

```
def f(df, lst):
    date = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
    MAX = date.max()
    bins = pd.to_timedelta([0]+lst, unit='D')
    labels = lst[:1] + ['_'.join(map(str, x)) for x in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
    group = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df['order_date']),
                   bins=(MAX-bins)[::-1],
                   labels=labels[::-1]
                  )
    return (df.groupby(['id', group], sort=False)['sales($)'].sum()
              .unstack(1)
              .add_prefix('last_').add_suffix('_days_sales')
              .reset_index()
              .rename_axis(columns=None)
           )

f(df, date_slicer_list)
```

output:

```
    id  last_30_60_days_sales  last_30_days_sales
0  139                     10                  50
1  164                     20                   0
2  432                      0                  20
3  474                      0                  10
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, related to the question, what if I want last_30_days_sales,last_60_days_sales instead of last_30_60_days_sales (i.e. cumulative sum)?

Comment: You can leave the bins ordered and `cumsum`

Answer (score 0):

```
bins=[0,30,60]

df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
df['days'] = (df['order_date'].max() - df['order_date']).dt.days

df2=(df.assign(grp=pd.cut(df['days'], bins=bins, include_lowest=True))
 .pivot_table(index='id', 
              columns='grp',
              values='sales($)' , 
              aggfunc='sum')
 .reset_index()
)
df2.columns=['last_'+str(col) +'_days_of_sales' if str(col)!='id' else col for col in df2.columns  ]
df2
```

```
id  last_(-0.001, 30.0]_days_of_sales   last_(30.0, 60.0]_days_of_sales
0   139     50  10
1   164     0   20
2   432     20  0
3   474     10  0
```